Django and Webpack5 - Implementing modern Javascript Tools
I am working on a Django project and want to enhance the front-end using npm and webpack5. My web development experience has been primarily with Django, and I'm new to npm and webpack. I've run into a few issues during this integration process and need some guidance. Also to note, I am using webpack5 and some knowledge on configuration seems limited (i.e. Asset Modules)
Here are some of the libraries I am including in my project:

Django v3.2
python 3.7.13
Node Libraries I am using

Bootstrap v5.3.3
Bootstrap-icons v1.11.3
jQuery v3.7.1
jQuery-ui v1.13.3
jQuery-validation v1.20.0
metro4-dist v4.5.0
webpack v5.91.0
webpack-cli v5.1.4
webpack-dev-server v5.0.4
[etc]



Tutorials/Guides I've Used
Sharing guides I used to help others in my scenario along their way.

Modern JavaScript for Django Developers : This helped me understand why npm and webpack were necessary.
Definitive Guide to Django and Webpack : Great guide for detailed configuration.
Learn Webpack - Full Tutorial for Beginners : Video that walks you through setup
Django with Webpack : Another video explaining how to configure webpack with a Django Project.

Coming from "Modern Javascript for Django" put it best for me on my situation.

First you learn Django. You go through the tutorial, learn about
models and views, and get your very first "hello world" application up
and running. You're on a roll!
Then, inevitably, you want to do something that requires a little
front-end interaction. Maybe a modal dialog, some real-time form
validation, or a mobile menu. It doesn't matter.
"No problem!" you say. "I'll use JavaScript for this!"
Django makes it easy to drop JavaScript directly into your HTML
templates, so you do some Googling and copy/paste some code from Stack
Overflow, maybe import jQuery and a plugin or two, and you're up and
running.
And it works great. Still on a roll!
Then, over time, there are more modals and more menus and more pages.
You start doing more complex things like managing state, dynamically
rendering components, and sharing code across templates.
It starts to feel unwieldy, but you keep pressing on. A document
selector here, an event callback there, maybe a few more libraries
imported on various pages as you need them. The front-end code slowly
expands through your Django templates and static files until it feels
like JavaScript has crept its tentacles throughout the entire
codebase.
At some point, your front-end code may start to feel like a spaghetti
monster—a tangled mess of code and dependencies spread across your
JavaScript and Django template files.

There are some great tutorials I have been able to find, but none seem to cater exactly where I need help. I think most of my issues boil down learning the concepts while following guides that have changed in implementation (i.e. webpack4 > webpack5)
Issues

openBrowser() does not work as intended
The function I wrote to launch a browser on the webpack-dev-server does not work as expected. Any suggestions for achieving this?

Configuring webpack-dev-server with Django for HMR
Integrating webpack-dev-server with Django's server for Hot Module Replacement has been challenging. I tried a few different methods, but I kept getting a blank webpage with the error "Cannot Get /" based on guides I followed.
Currently, what does work is the proxy option on the devServer config and writeToDisk option for devMiddleware. I question if there is a better/optimal approach? Can I make it where Django's server can read the bundled files via memory?

Bundled Files Not Recognized with Certain URLs
When viewing the browser's dev tools, I can see the page source for my bundeled files when my URL is:

http://localhost:8080/
http://localhost:8080/help
http://localhost:8080/sysetms/
http://localhost:8080/sites/

But my bundled files are not recognized if I try to navigate to a page like:

http://localhost:8080/report/site/[some_name]/
http://localhost:8080/report/system/[some_name]/

How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

webpack-dev-server launches http://localhost:80801/
Why is port 8081 being used instead of 8080? Is this because Django's server is using 8080 too? I can manually go to port 8080 and my application is available, but I don't understand why this is happening.

SVGs are not working
In my HTML templates, I am trying to use the SVG Sprite usage Bootstrap illustrates
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use href="bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill"/>
</svg>

Is it because of my path? I don't point this to the node_modules/ directory, correct?


Configuration
Notes

I utilize some of Django's template tags to help with organization of sub templates (i.e. {% include subtemplate.html %} or {$% block content %} {% endblock content %} so not all HTML templates need the bundled files included via HTMLWebpackPlugin - that is why I use the inject: false option for those instances.
HtmlWebpackPlugin outputs all the HTML templates in the templates/ folder of root directory for Django to operate in best practices.
When running the webpack-dev-server, I want to default using Google Chrome browser. If that is not available on the host machine, then use the host's default browser.
I use a lot of SVG sprites from Bootstrap-icons throughout my templates, one icon from metro4-dist, and I have a few .pdf documents that I want webpack to create in the dist/ folder under their respective directories. I read its better to make SVG's inline vs creating there own file, correct?
I know by default, webpack places the output files in dist/ and Django looks for its source files in static/, so the configuration has to change for one of them. I made Django static url read from the "/dist/"

Project Folder Structure
project-name/
├── app1/
├── app2/
├── app3/
├── app4/
├── src/
│  ├── js
|  │  └── ...my custom .js files
│  ├── styles
|  │  ├── main.scss
|  │  └── ...my custom .css files
│  ├── templates
|  │  └── ...my custom .html files
│  ├── index.js
│  └── vendor.js
├── static/
├── webpack/
|  ├── webpack.config.common.js
|  ├── webpack.config.dev.js
|  └── webpack.config.prod.js
├── package.json
├── .gitignore
├── project-name/
│  ├── settings.py
│  └── urls.py
└── ...other files

package.json
{
    "name": "[removed for privacy]",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "description": "[removed for privacy]",
    "exports": "./index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
        "html-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.0",
        "open": "^10.1.0",
        "prettier": "^3.2.5",
        "prettier-plugin-organize-attributes": "^1.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.77.0",
        "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
        "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
        "webpack": "^5.91.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.10.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.6.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.13.3",
        "jquery-validation": "^1.20.0",
        "metro4-dist": "^4.5.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=16"
    }
}


webpack.config.common.js
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin"
import path from "path"
import {fileURLToPath} from "url"

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

export default {
    entry: {
        vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/vendor.js"),
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.js"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/base.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/base.html"),
            minify: false,
            favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, "../static/images/favicon.ico"),
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/circuit_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/circuit_form.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/circuit_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/circuit_report.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/csd-series_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/csd-series_form.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/csd-series_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/csd-series_report.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/footer.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/footer.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/help.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/help.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/home.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/home.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/navbar.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/navbar.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/results.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/results.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/site_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/site_form.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/site_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/site_report.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/system_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/system_form.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/system_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/system_report.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
    ],
}

webpack.config.dev.js
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin"
import open from "open"
import path from "path"
import {fileURLToPath} from "url"
import {merge} from "webpack-merge"
import common from "./webpack.config.common.js"

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
const url = "http://localhost:8080"

function getBrowserName() {
    if (process.platform === "darwin") {
        return "Google Chrome"
    } else if (process.platform === "linux") {
        return "google-chrome"
    } else {
        return "chrome"
    }
}

async function openBrowser(url) {
    const browserName = getBrowserName()
    try {
        await open(url, {
            app: {
                name: browserName,
            },
        })
        console.log(`Opened devServer with URL: ${url}`)
    } catch (error) {
        await open(url)
        console.error(
            "Failed to open devServer with Google Chrome browser. Opening in default browser instead.",
        )
    }
}

const config = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
        clean: true,
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        proxy: [
            {
                context: ["**"],
                target: url,
            },
        ],
        open: openBrowser(url),
        devMiddleware: {
            writeToDisk: true,
        },
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "[name].css"})],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Extract css into its own file
                    "css-loader", // 2. Turns css into commonjs
                    "sass-loader", // 1. Turns sass into css
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                use: ["html-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                type: "asset/inline",
                generator: {
                    filename: "images/[name][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "images/[name][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|txt)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "documents/[name][ext]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
})

export default config

webpack.config.prod.js
import CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin from "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin"
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin"
import path from "path"
import TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin"
import {fileURLToPath} from "url"
import {merge} from "webpack-merge"
import common from "./webpack.config.common.js"

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

const config = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
        clean: true,
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()],
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "[name].[contenthash].css"})],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Extract css into its own file
                    "css-loader", // 2. Turns css into commonjs
                    "sass-loader", // 1. Turns sass into css
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                use: ["html-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/i,
                type: "asset/inline",
                generator: {
                    filename: "images/[name].[hash][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "images/[name].[hash][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|txt)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "documents/[name].[hash][ext]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
})

export default config

Django settings.py
[..some code..]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

# These settings are for Django serving the static files (Custom files)
STATIC_URL = "/dist/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "dist"),
]

# This setting is for Apache serving the static files (Admin Page)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/admin")


You're right, first time adding a frontend server is a mess, esp. for a solo dev. Note this is usually something a completely separate team will work on.
If your use-case for front-end is not extremely complex (e.g. a SPA) have you considered something much simpler like Alpine.JS or HTMX? These integrate simply through CDN and can get you very far.

I did investigate this idea as alt option because I do perform several AJAX requests, but unfortunately, a SPA setup would not be preferred for this application. I say this because MPA I think handles applications with "menus" better

You mention a SPA setup is not preferred. I agree, can you try Alpine.JS via CDN for example? Removing the complexity of another server interacting with your site when your use-case is simple will save you a lot of overhead, scope creep and maintenance headaches in future.

I haven't been able to research Alpine.JS - what will this provide me exactly? I guess I should add my application is fully functional and operating - I was only looking at NPM and webpack to improve the management of my application (I.e. not storing 3rd party libraries in my repo, ease of collaborating with teammates)

UPDATE #1
I'm going to address a few of my issues that I have since resolved to help anyone following this post. Don't worry, I'll also include my entire, updated config below as well.
Issues I have Resolved

Configuring webpack-dev-server with Django for HMR
In short, once I resolved other issues I was experiencing, HMR seemed to be working as expected. I still utilize the proxy option and have not figured out if I can make Django read bundled files from memory, but this will do for now.

Bundled Files Not Recognized with Certain URLs
This was an easy fix, but I still don't understand why my bundled files were even read in the first place. The fix was declaring the publicPath in Webpack's output. I'm still a novice but I think the combination of the bundled files path (originally webpack was generating a relative path <script defer src="../dist/vendor.bundle.js">) and my URLs having single slugs vs. multiple slugs made it work some instances but not others? When I viewed the browser's dev tools during the error, I noticed the URL path to the bundled files were http://localhost:8080/report/system/dist/vendor.bundle.js which I knew was not right - should I have read http://localhost:8080/dist/vendor.bundle.js. That's when I realized the relative path notation was causing issues. Here is that portion of the config. Remember, I am telling Django my static URL is "/dist/" in Django's settings.py.
output: {
   filename: "[name].bundle.js",
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
   publicPath: "/dist/", // This is requried to help set the path correctly
   clean: true,
 },


webpack-dev-server launches http://localhost:80801/
I believe this issue happens because my openBrowser() function does not work as intended, so webpack-dev-server launches both Chrome and Safari webpages instead of just Chrome. 8081 is being used for the secondary webpage being launched.

SVGs are not working
My project adds SVGs in two different ways and this required two approaches. One method is hardcoded in HTML files where needed (i.e. the navbar, static buttons). Another method is when I add a block of HTML code dynamically with JS using template literals "back-tick".

The first method required any of my HTML files that are using an SVG, the path looks like this
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
    <use href="~bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill"/>
</svg>

webpack knows where to look for the SVG Sprite with the Tilda symbol in the path. When HTMLWebpackPlugin reads the path of this SVG, it correctly puts the new path for this SVG (i.e. href=/dist/icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill)

The second method required my JS files to have the import at the top like so
import bootstrapIcons from "bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg"

...and anywhere I am adding an SVG in a template literal, I add it like this
<svg
    class="bi me-2"
    height="20"
    width="20"
    fill="currentColor"
>
    <use
       href="${bootstrapIcons}#telephone"
    ></use>
</svg>

You can not include the path like previously because webpack reads this as a string and not a required() function. This post helped me.


To add, I did modify my webpack config a little to include extensions like woff/woff2/eot/ttf/otf files in the "icons/" directory as well - not sure if that is accurate but was trying to organize stuff. Here is were I did that
   {
      test: /\.(|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/i,
      type: "asset/resource",
      generator: {
         filename: "icons/[name][ext]",
      },
   },



Additional Issues I Resolved that surfaced after my First Post

PDF/static Documents Not Loading Correctly
I had to make some changes in the webpack config for the "html-loader" module to know how to handle anchor, , tags with the "href" attribute because I don't want webpack to also include instances where I have a hyperlink that uses Django's render function (aka passing values from the view to template) - webpack doesn't know how to read {{ some_django_view_value }}. Basically needed to be able to filter some anchor tags the "html-loader" was seeing. To illustrate, my HTML could have the two following anchor tags:
<a class="nav-link nav-toggle d-flex align-items-center collapsed link-body-emphasis"
   data-bs-toggle="collapse"
   href="#create-new-menu"
>
   <svg class="bi me-2" height="30" width="30" fill="currentColor"
   >
      <use
         href="~bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#chevron-right"

      ></use>
   </svg>
   <svg class="bi me-2" height="30" width="30" fill="currentColor"
   >
      <use
         href="~bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#clipboard-plus"
      ></use>
   </svg>
   Create New...
</a>

and...
<a href="/some/URL/{{ using_django_view_value }}/link"
   class="nav-link d-flex align-items-center loading link-body-emphasis"
>
   <svg class="bi me-2" height="30" width="30" fill="currentColor"
   >
      <use
         href="~bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#pin-map"
      ></use>
   </svg>
   Location
</a>

hopefully that highlights the two differences.
To fix, I made my "html-loader" look like so. Was able to gather the idea from here and here
{
   test: /\.html$/i,
   loader: "html-loader",
   options: {
      sources: {
         list: [
            "...",
            {
               tag: "a",
               attribute: "href",
               type: "src",
               filter: (tag, attribute, attributes) => {
                  return attributes.some(
                     (attr) => /\.(pdf|txt)$/i.test(attr.value),
                  )
               },
            },
         ],
      },
   },
},



Update #1 Configuration
Notes

Although webpack-dev-server and HMR is working, I will say the openBrowser() function I have in my webpack.config.dev.js does not work - so I still get multiple browsers launching (my system's default browser and the preferred browser).
I wanted webpack to use only two configs, dev and prod. For dev configs, I wanted to further extract if I wanted to run webpack-dev-server or just "build" the config. You will see my npm script "start" passes an environment variable to help create this condition.
Want to ensure my front-end code uses ESM and not CommonJS. (I had to understand the history of this to know why I was seeing different configs for similar outputs)

Also included notes from previous post...

I utilize some of Django's template tags to help with organization of sub templates (i.e. {% include subtemplate.html %} or {$% block content %} {% endblock content %} so not all HTML templates need the bundled files included via HTMLWebpackPlugin - that is why I use the inject: false option for those instances.
HtmlWebpackPlugin outputs all the HTML templates in the templates/ folder of root directory for Django to operate in best practices.
I know by default, webpack places the output files in dist/ and Django looks for its source files in static/, so the configuration has to change for one of them. I made Django static url read from the "/dist/"
Watching a few videos on node projects, I realized I can reduce my package.json by removing bloat options that are not necessary for my project. Just made sure I set the option private: true.

package.json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack serve --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --env devserver",
        "build-dev": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js --watch",
        "build-prod": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "css-loader": "^7.1.1",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.0",
        "html-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.9.0",
        "open": "^10.1.0",
        "prettier": "^3.2.5",
        "prettier-plugin-organize-attributes": "^1.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.77.0",
        "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
        "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
        "webpack": "^5.91.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4",
        "webpack-merge": "^5.10.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.6.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
        "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.13.3",
        "jquery-validation": "^1.20.0",
        "metro4-dist": "^4.5.0"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=16"
    }
}

webpack.config.common.js
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin"
import path from "path"
import {fileURLToPath} from "url"

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

const config = {
    entry: {
        vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/vendor.js"),
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/index.js"),
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/base.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/base.html"),
            minify: false,
            favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, "../static/images/favicon.ico"),
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/circuit_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/circuit_form.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/circuit_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/circuit_report.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/csd-series_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/csd-series_form.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/csd-series_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/csd-series_report.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/footer.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/footer.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/help.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/help.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/home.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/home.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/navbar.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/navbar.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/templates/results.html"),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/results.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/site_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/site_form.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/site_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/site_report.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/system_form.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "../templates/system_form.html"),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../src/templates/system_report.html",
            ),
            filename: path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "../templates/system_report.html",
            ),
            minify: false,
            inject: false,
        }),
    ],
}

export default config

webpack.config.dev.js
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin"
import open from "open"
import path from "path"
import {fileURLToPath} from "url"
import {merge} from "webpack-merge"
import common from "./webpack.config.common.js"

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
const url = "http://localhost:8080"
const isDevServer = process.argv.indexOf("devserver") > -1

function getBrowserName() {
    if (process.platform === "darwin") {
        return "Google Chrome"
    } else if (process.platform === "linux") {
        return "google-chrome"
    } else {
        return "chrome"
    }
}

async function openBrowser(url) {
    const browserName = getBrowserName()
    try {
        await open(url, {
            app: {
                name: browserName,
            },
        })
        console.log(`Opened devServer with URL: ${url}`)
    } catch (error) {
        await open(url)
        console.error(
            "Failed to open devServer with Google Chrome browser. Opening in default browser instead.",
        )
    }
}

const config = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/", // This is requried to help set the path correctly
        clean: true,
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    devServer: isDevServer
        ? {
              hot: true,
              proxy: [
                  {
                      context: ["**"],
                      target: url,
                  },
              ],
              open: openBrowser(url),
              devMiddleware: {
                  writeToDisk: true,
              },
          }
        : undefined, // Do not include devServer in "build-dev" mode
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "[name].css"})],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Extract css into its own file
                    "css-loader", // 2. Turns css into commonjs
                    "sass-loader", // 1. Turns sass into css
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                    sources: {
                        list: [
                            "...",
                            {
                                tag: "a",
                                attribute: "href",
                                type: "src",
                                filter: (tag, attribute, attributes) => {
                                    return attributes.some((attr) =>
                                        /\.(pdf|txt)$/i.test(attr.value),
                                    )
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "icons/[name][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "images/[name][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|txt)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "documents/[name][ext]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
})

export default config

webpack.config.prod.js
import CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin from "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin"
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin"
import path from "path"
import TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin"
import {fileURLToPath} from "url"
import {merge} from "webpack-merge"
import common from "./webpack.config.common.js"

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

const config = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
        publicPath: "/dist/", // This is requried to help set the path correctly
        clean: true,
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new CssMinimizerWebpackPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()],
    },
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "[name].[contenthash].css"})],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // 3. Extract css into its own file
                    "css-loader", // 2. Turns css into commonjs
                    "sass-loader", // 1. Turns sass into css
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                    sources: {
                        list: [
                            "...",
                            {
                                tag: "a",
                                attribute: "href",
                                type: "src",
                                filter: (tag, attribute, attributes) => {
                                    return attributes.some((attr) =>
                                        /\.(pdf|txt)$/i.test(attr.value),
                                    )
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|svg)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "icons/[name][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "images/[name].[hash][ext]",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(pdf|txt)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "documents/[name].[hash][ext]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
})

export default config

